# Google Map won't load on my android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make a google maps application for android. I followed the tutorial from google developers website but I cannot get the map to load.

I am using SupportMapFragment, the API Key it's set correctly.

Here it's a printscreen from my phone

http://s33.postimg.org/4l29xr5jz/Screenshot_2016_06_11_16_18_38.png

If someone have any ideea why is this happening i will realy apreciate the help.

*EDIT*

I tried for the first time to run the app from android studio directly into my phone to see the logcat and the map loads perfectly. But when using Build > Generate Signed APK it remains like in the photo.

Comment: It's likely you've not set up an api key properly.  Check the logcat output for an error message.

Comment: The API key it's set correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a MapView rather than a map fragment, you'll need to ensure that you handle life cycle methods yourself (e.g. onCreate(...), onResume(), onDestroy() etc).

I imagine the issue is more likely to be API key related though so ensure that you have the keystore and your app's SHA-1 key correct in the developer console.

Comment: I am using SupportMapFragment  and the API key it's set correctly. The thing is that when I install it from android studio the map works but if i generate the apk it's not loading

Comment: It could be that you're using a debug keystore that the API key was generated from, but when you generate the release apk, it's using a different keystore. Have a look through your build.gradle file and see if the keystore is linked to the release buildType and also that the apk that you're generating has the correct keystore associated with it.